# Why are missing font shapes so common?

Tags: fonts

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

%\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}
    \section{Hello}

    Test here
\end{document}
```

When compiling this as-is, the compilation works as expected, but as soon as I uncomment the usepackage line, I get a font warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/jkp/m/n' undefined using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 5.
```

and the section title is no longer in bold face.

I have to wonder though: How can a seemingly common font (after all it is taken from https://r2src.github.io/top10fonts/, so it can't be super niche, can it?) have issues with simple bold text? I mean that does seem like a super common thing to have.

And this problem does not only apply to the `kpfonts` package. I tried several fonts so far (a few from https://r2src.github.io/top10fonts/) and so far my experience seems to be that as soon as I switch away from the default Computer Modern, some font issues arise due to missing font shapes/styles.

So my question is: Why are these kind of errors apparently so common? Am I missing something obvious that is needed to properly switch fonts without running into trouble? Does the Computer Modern font just contain exceptionally many shapes/styles?

In case it is relevant: I am using latexmk and lualatex to compile my documents.

Comment: The kpfonts are not for lualatex, that is a font package meant for pdflatex only. So yes it is very relevant that you use lualatex.

Comment: you are using luatex set up for Unicode (TU encoding) and kpfonts are a set of classic 8bit fonts for classic tex so do not work at all and the message that you show shows lualatex reverting to latin modern, so basically this is user error

Comment: `kpfonts` uses a different package name for Unicode engines. If you want to use `kpfonts` with LuaLaTeX, load `kpfonts-otf`.

Comment: Ah yes indeed. Using `kpfonts-otf` fixes the observed issue. Is there an easy way to know which fonts work with unicode or do I just have to read the respective package's documentation?

Comment: unlike pdftex you usually (or at least often) don't need a font-specific package as the fonts are all in standard layout so do not need custom macros, if you use fontspec you can reference a font such as `\setmainfont{Times Roman}`   to access any opentype fonts installed in your system, not requiring special "latex fonts" as in the document you reference in your question

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much!